# when using setPropertiesToFetch in coredata, how to get the count in each result?

Tags: core-data

In my application, I use coredata to store a large set of contacts. And I need to know the all the first names with their responding count.
for example, if the data set contains six people:Bill Gates, Bill jordan, Bill Clinton, Mike jordan, Mike jobs, Tom Clinton.
I need to get the results: Bill with count 3, Mike with count 2, Tom with count 1.

If I try this:

```
[fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"firstName"];
[fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```

Then I can only get 3 dictionary with the value of the first name. But I can't get the count.
If I use the default result type, I will get six managed objects. Iteration the loop to get the first name and calculate its count takes a extra time cost.

So my question is, how to get the values of a specific property and its count as fast as possible?
Thank you very much.

By the way, I have also tried to use `NSFetchResultController` with the keyNamePath, and try to get the section infos. But the speed is very slow when there are many sections. It is more slowly than I get all the sorted managedObject and count the property myself.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by a large set of contacts? Depending on the scale, the problem is definitely not the same.

Whatever, it may worth to use the database capabilities to handle the problem nicely.

```
Person
- firstName -> FirstName
- lastName -> LastName

FirstName
- name: string
- persons ->> Person

LastName
- name: string
- persons ->> Person
```

Starting with these entities (tables), it is much easier to know how many names are shared by how many persons. Still, that's certainly a fair amount of requests to the database, so it may greatly help to add a counter, likewise:

```
FirstName
- name: string
- persons ->> Person
- personCount: integer

LastName
- name: string
- persons ->> Person
- personCount: integer
```

Of course you'll have to maintain the counter in sync, but then it will be very easy to get the data you want, whatever the number of entries.

(It may even use less disk space than a simple table.)

Comment: Thank you very much, Adding new table and relationship will help. But if there are many properties which I would like to get and count, I should maintain many extra tables. As a result, if the coredata's fetchquest has provided an api to get fetch the properties with its count, I think the solution will be better.
As to the larget dataset, I have tested that in iPhone4, I have 5000 managedObject and 94 last name sections, using NSFetchedResultController takes 7.7 seconds. But without using sections, it only takes 0.4 seconds.

Comment: If I loop over the sorted managedObject and section the datas my self, it takes 3.1 seconds.  But I think the 3.1 seconds can be reduced if coredata could get directly fetch the properties with its count.